# How to handle feeds of Database Updates on Multiple Client WInforms

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

We are developing an Desktop Applications on Winforms in C# with a single backend system or Database as Postgresql. The Desktop Applications will be used by multiple users on a Local Lan or on a WAN where my Database server will be placed on a WAN.

The users are going to perform update, insert, delete on the Database tables. What i need is when any user performs any of  the above three operations, automatically other users who are logged in or will log in after some times, gets to see in a winforms about the activities performed by the other user.
Please help me on how should i proceed with the same.

Regards
Vineet More

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [message queue service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queuing_service).

Workflow would go like this:

1. custom service will use postgresql [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-listen.html) to "collect" notifications from PostgreSQL and feed as messages into MQS
2. Inside PostgreSQL you can use pgsql NOTIFY to notify custom services from within trigger for example.
3. Application would be reading messages from MQS and presents to the users on UI.

Regards
H