# How to handle Database Updates on Multiple Client Winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

My question is similar to this link.

[How to handle feeds of Database Updates on Multiple Client WInforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906562/how-to-handle-feeds-of-database-updates-on-multiple-client-winforms)

Still I could not able to find a satisfying answer.

My database is MYSQL not postgreSQL. As far as I researched there is no "LISTEN" and "NOTIFY" feature in MYSQL.
The other option is to use SQLDEPENDENCY, again there is no option as MYSQLDEPENDENCY.

I read in some article that polling a database for every second affects the performance and it is not recommended.

Is there any third party library to achieve this work without polling the database for every second in MYSQL?

Comment: This link may help you do what you need. You'll still need to poll manually , but you can use this to only select the new records thus increasing performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665227/whats-the-fastest-way-to-poll-a-mysql-table-for-new-rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167254/watching-a-table-for-change-in-mysql